# jQuery: how to know the div already exists?

Tags: jquery

I'm developing a web application, need to append some text to a specific div(id=div_specific). The div is dynamic generated by program, so I need to verify if the div already exists, otherwise, I have to create that div first. How to verify if the div already exists?

Comment: Do you need to know how to create it too? I've included that, just in case... (assuming you know the id of the parent div?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if(jQuery("#id_specific").length > 0) {
   ...
}

else {
   ...
}
```

Comment: The div might do not have any content at first.

Comment: @Steve That doesn't matter. jQuery returns an array of elements, so you're checking to see if that array of elements is greater than 0. You're not checking the length of the contents of the div.

Comment: jQuery(...).length doesn't check for content in the div, it checks for the number of items matching the search paramater (in this case id=id_specific)

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick,

```
if($('#' + div_specific).length == 1){
  alert("I Exist");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if($("#div_specific").length == 1) { /* do stuff */ }
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

```
  if($("#mydivname").length) {
    // do something cool with the div
  } else {
    // create it
    $("#mydivparent").append("<div id='mydivname'>hello world</div>")
    // now do something cool with the new div
  }
```

Comment: So I realised you wanted to create it if it didn't exist - duly edited.